shared_vpc / terraform - in simple words - how to share different subnets with chosen service projects?
If possible, can we use Terraform to have different subnets shared with specific service projects?
so, sharedVPC :

+---------------------+
|     Host Project    |
|   +---------------+ |
|   |  VPC Network  | |
|   |               | |
|   |   +---------+ | |
|   |   | Subnet A || <--- Shared with Service Project 1
|   |   +---------+ | |
|   |               | |
|   |   +---------+ | |
|   |   | Subnet B || <--- Shared with Service Project 2
|   |   +---------+ | |
|   +---------------+ |
+---------------------+
         |    |
         |    |------------------------------|
         v                                   v
+---------------------+          +---------------------+
|  Service Project 1  |          |  Service Project 2  |
|                     |          |                     |
|   Can access only   |          |   Can access only   |
|       Subnet A      |          |       Subnet B      |          
+---------------------+          +---------------------+


Thanks in advance !
I just trying use terraform to do it, and I cant find any solution in the internet.
